Как правильно синхронизировать кастомные изменения в библиотеках сторонних производителей внутри проекта
Я использую в своем проекте некую библиотеку, написанную сторонним производителем. Для моего функционала нужно было внести в код этой библиотеки изменения. И у меня возник вопрос - как правильно (как принято) синхронизировать данные изменения. Ведь я вынужден буду, при установке окружения на другую машину, помнить, что я расковырял код библиотеки и требуется замена некоторых модулей, которые отличаются от дефолтной инсталляции. Выглядит не очень юзабильно. У меня пока есть пара мыслей - внести измененные модули в GIT-репозиторий вместе со всем проектом или применить контейнеры (docker). Я откровенно говоря, не до конца еще понимаю как контейнеры работают, но чувствую - надо разобраться.
Буду благодарен за любые советы, направление поиска и т.д.

Комитьте свои изменения и свой форк того репозитория и используйте его в дальнейшем.

@user7860670 Вы имеете ввиду репозиторий разработчика библиотеки или мой репозиторий проекта?

Я имею ввиду отдельный новый репозиторий для этой библиотеки.

@user7860670 А, понял! Спасибо!

Попробуйте связаться с автором библиотеки, и предложите ему включить свои правки

@ГерманБорисов спасибо, хорошая мысль!
